# Print date after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime, datepicker

I have Invoice Panel in my e-shop application.

I would like to print download date (no today date) after click my link. Is it possible to make it easy?

```
<a class="download-invoice" target="_blank" 
                href="?{=orderGroup.invoiceHref}">#{Download}</a>
```

Comment: But on click you are opening the Download in a new Window, so where do you want to print the date on the parent window? Question not clear.

Comment: Yes. I want to print date on window with invoices list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple demo how you can get the date at the time the link is clicked. Off course you'll have to save this date somehow, so you can show it later.

```js
function printDate(num) {
  var date = new Date();

 document.querySelector('.dateContainer_' + num).innerHTML = date.toDateString();
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="download-invoice" target="_blank" href="#" onClick="printDate(1)">Download 1</a>
    <span class="dateContainer_1"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="download-invoice" target="_blank" href="#" onClick="printDate(2)">Download 2</a>
    <span class="dateContainer_2"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="download-invoice" target="_blank" href="#" onClick="printDate(3)">Download 3</a>
    <span class="dateContainer_3"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    etc...
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Work greate. But i have list with ~70 invoices. When I click 1st Download Link - Date is showing next to "Download". But, when I click 2nd, 3th link, date is showing also next to 1st Download Link.

Comment: I have updated the code to account for multiple links. I don't know which server-side language you use, but you can auto-generate the numbers in a 'for loop' or a similar construct. Or if you have a unique id attached to the invoices, this would even be better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function printDateAndDownload(hrefUrl) {
  var date = new Date();

 document.querySelector('.dateContainer').innerHTML = date.toDateString();
 
 window.open(window.url + "?" + hrefUrl)
return false;
}
```

```html
<a class="download-invoice" onClick="printDateAndDownload({=orderGroup.invoiceHref})">Download</a>

<div class="dateContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Not working. When I click Download i'm going to domain.com/#. Date not showing on and file is not downloaded.